# Colored Text Name Glitch

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried the colored text trick for my name on Minecraft Pocket Edition and now I can't type anything for my name, but when I do I see blank spaces (no words!). HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me i don't know what to do try backing up your device then delete minecraft and redownload it. All your worlds should still be there a hopefully the name will be fixe

Comment: Sorry then reload the backup on to your device

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there is no fix right now so just do nothing but the most important thing is to make sure that you don't delete minecraft I tried and it deleted my worlds

Answer (score -1):

Ok so the Same exact thing happens to me simply do nothing you may not be able to join servers so just wait until the bug is fixed or report it deleting it will remove your worlds check back a week later still nothing report it so they can fix it.

Comment: If this is indeed a known bug with no current fix, perhaps link to the minecraft forums, or somewhere reporting the issue.